# Grouping classes with an interface in Java

Tags: java, oop, interface, grouping

I have 40 classes of tags that extend from 4 super classes. I would like to categorize each of these 40 classes to either a technical tag or a user tag.

I am only interested in technical tags. Would it be good design to make an interface `TechnicalTag` that has no methods inside it and implement it in say each of that class that I want to be a technical tag so that I can use `instanceOf` to pick them?

The reason I do not want a method `isTechnicalTag` that returns a `boolean` is because that would mean I will have to implement them in all the 40 classes. And the technical tag for now is perhaps only 4 of them.

Kindly advise me. OOP is not exactly what I am trained on.

Comment: Yes, this will be good approach, however annotating your classes would be even better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This approach is a design pattern known as the `Marker Interface`. You an read more about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marker_interface_pattern). Java employ this all over their code. One example is the [Serializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) interface, that contains no inherit methods, but allows the class that implements it to be serialized.

It's perfectly fine to take this approach. This approach also makes your code quite extensible. For example, by programming to an interface (another thing Java *loves*), you decouple knowledge of the class itself from the class that is using it. This means, for example, if you want to change methods that exist inside of the original object, let's say it's `Tag`, then you can do so, without ever needing to change the class that uses this object as a `TechnicalTag` interface.

**Annotations**

I've seen mentioned in the comments about annotations. This is another approach that you can take which would result in some very nice, clean code. You an read extensively about annotations, and their use [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_annotation).

As a brief summary, you could write something like:

```
@TechnicalTag
public class MyTag
{
    // Code for my tag.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually the idea of OO programming is not that you do different things in your main program depending on the actual implementation of the objects you manage, but that you write your program to the interfaces and then the concrete implementations hide the details of what they are doing.

This said, we all know there are some classes that implement 'special' interfaces such as `RandomAccess` even in the JDK, and the purpose of `RandomAccess` is the same as you need... so your idea is not at all strange if you feel the need for it.

Answer (score 1):

You can create interfaces as you said in this case it's going to be marker interface. You can read more about that here:

> http://javarevisited.blogspot.co.uk/2012/01/what-is-marker-interfaces-in-java-and.html

Answer (score 0):

You can have default implementation for the isTechnicalTag() method which returns "false" by default.

Only in the classes that you want to be technical, you can override this method and return true.

Comment: yeah, okay. But still thats quite some work to click on 40 classes to implement unimplemented methods and remove the TODO comment :)

Comment: Don't you have common super class where you can implement isTechnicalTag()?

Comment: It cannot be identified in any super class unfortunately.

Comment: Then @christopher answer above is the way to go.